# Is it possible to specify synonyms in a Bing Custom Search instance?

Tags: search, search-engine, bing, bing-api

I'm setting up a Bing Custom Search instance and have some requirements around configuring industry-specific synonyms e.g. searching for either DD or Direct Debit should return the same results with the word "direct debit" Highlighted

There doesn't appear to be any reference to it in the [Bing custom search documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/) however the regular Azure Search does have support for [Synonym Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/synonym-map-operations)